# sIFIR doesn't work when saved in Flash CS4

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, sifr3

I am trying to use (sIFR) version 3, revision 419

When i test the defaults SWF files( that came whit the package ), it works fine.
But when i edit with my own fonts, it does not work properly.

Is there any issue, or something that i must to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your own fonts have the glyphs you want to use, eg if you are using a font with Cyrillic that does not have the characters. Use charmap.exe on pc to check which glyphs are in the fonts you want to use. As a test you can use Arial as that has just about everything in it.